# Compute $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(n+1)}{n!}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Compute $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(n+1)}{n!}$

$\frac{(n+1)}{n!}$ remembers me to $\frac{n+1}{n}$, which is $(1+\frac{1}{n})$ and it's limit if we take the $n^{th}$ power is $e$. Can I maybe use it to compute the sum of it?

Comment: Just split it into $\sum\frac n{n!}+\sum\frac1{n!}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Olivier Oloa already mentioned, you can rewrite this.

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(n+1)}{n!}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{n!}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n-1)!}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!}
$$

You can now solve using the knowledge that 
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!}= e 
$$
Because that means
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!} = \left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!} \right) - \frac{1}{0!} = e-1
$$ 
and
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n-1)!} =  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!} = e
$$ 
so 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(n+1)}{n!}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{n!}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n-1)!}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!} = e + e-1 = 2e -1
$$

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**. One may write
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(n+1)}{n!}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{n!}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n-1)!}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!}.
$$

Comment: Should I check the expressions : $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n-1)!}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!}.$ with the ratio test?

Comment: @Zauberkerl No, you should try to evaluate each one separately. Note that they differ only by one element.

Answer (score 2):

*The long way when compared to Olivier Oloa's answer.*

Consider $$S=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(n+1)}{n!} x^n$$ Integrate it $$T=\int S \,dx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{ x^{n+1}}{n!}=x\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{ x^{n}}{n!}=x\left(-1+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{ x^{n}}{n!}\right)=x\left(e^x-1 \right)$$ Differentiate $$T'=S=\frac d{dx}\left(x\left(e^x-1 \right)\right)=xe^x +e^x-1$$ Make $x=1$ and get $S=2e-1$

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach using generating functions:

$e^x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}$

$\Rightarrow xe^x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n+1}}{n!}$

$\Rightarrow \frac{\text{d}xe^x}{\text{d}x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(n+1)x^{n}}{n!}$

$\Rightarrow \frac{\text{d}xe^x}{\text{d}x}-1=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(n+1)x^{n}}{n!}$